# Break down a column of multiple strings per cell into unqiue single cell strings

Tags: excel

I have a column of data pulled from a database that I need to sort out into graphs and visual data. The column can contain one or more different strings in each cell, but I need to pick out the unique strings. The strings are separated by a semicolon and contain letters, numbers and spaces.

Example:

- ABC-23 Up;BCD-1 Hi;CDE-5
- CDE-5
- ABC-23 Up;HJK-3

I want to end up in a column of:

- ABC-23 Up
- BCD-1 Hi
- CDE-5
- HJK-3

Currently I use the excel function "text to columns" to split apart the column into however many cells I need based on the ';' as the split, and then do an advanced filter to remove duplicates but I was hoping there is a more automated way in case someone else has to pull the same information. Any ideas?

Comment: To confirm - do you want duplicates to be removed? Also, are you familiar with VBA? Are you familiar with Excel's string comparison functions? (Such as Search / Mid)

Comment: Yes I want duplicates to be removed, and I am familiar with VBA and the comparison functions. Its just the combining them appropriately part in an efficient manner that is eluding me so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like my post here may be of use (assuming you're ok with a non-VBA solution, that is):

http://excelxor.com/2014/09/30/list-of-unique-entries-from-column-of-space-separated-strings/

Obviously you'd make amendments where appropriate to the delimiter being referenced, e.g. space to semi-colon.

Regards

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful! Walking through it now. Non-VBA is just as useful as VBA in this instance so I appreciate it.

Comment: Sure. Let me know of any issues you come across.

Comment: How can I modify Arry3 so that only a semicolon is considered a delimiter?

Comment: Change the first occurrence only of " " to ";". I trust you performed this same operation for Arry1?

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how to change Arry3 correctly then, but I forgot Arry1. Your explanation in the link is very informative, I'm fascinated reading it.

Comment: That's very kind of you! Hope you can get it working for your set-up. Keep me posted of any issues that arise.